# Create list of unique object pairs

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QVector of instances of an object `Atom`, where each `Atom` instance contains a set of cartesian coordinates and a unique index identifier, among other attributes. I have also defined a `Dyad` container, which is just a tuple of two `Atom` instances. Basically, if my two `Atom` instances satisfy a distance constraint, I want to be able to construct a QList of `Dyad`s.

Say I had a `Dyad` of (`Atom1`,`Atom2`), how could I ensure that my QList did not already contain a Dyad of (`Atom2`, `Atom1`)?

I have already tried to use the QList `.contains()` function and have overloaded my `==` operator, but I cannot get it to work. I can attach the code that I have tried insofar as trying to use the `contains()` function if that would help.

// Function Definition

`QList<AtomDyad> getUniqueAtomPairs(QVector<Atom> atomVector) {`

```
QList<AtomDyad> AtomDyadPairList;

for (int iatom = 0; iatom < atomVector.size(); iatom++) {
    for (int jatom = 0; jatom < atomVector.size(); jatom++) {

        if (iatom == jatom) { continue; }

        float x1 = atomVector[jatom].getX();
        float x2 = atomVector[iatom].getX();

        float y1 = atomVector[jatom].getY();
        float y2 = atomVector[iatom].getY();

        float z1 = atomVector[jatom].getZ();
        float z2 = atomVector[iatom].getZ();

        float Radii_Sum1 = atomVector[jatom].getvdW_radius(atomVector[jatom]) + atomVector[iatom].getvdW_radius(atomVector[iatom]);

        if (DistanceBetween3DPoints(x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2) <= Radii_Sum1) {
            AtomDyad MyDyad(atomVector[iatom], atomVector[jatom]);
            // How can I ensure that MyDyad(atomVector[jatom], atomVector[iatom]) does not already exist?
            AtomDyadPairList.append(MyDyad);
        }
    }
}

return AtomDyadPairList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I know exactly how your `Atom` and `AtomDyad` classes look like, but I will mimic them in a simple example to help you to get the idea. I assume, that `Atom` has three coordinates: x, y and z. Let's code now:

```
struct Atom
{
  Atom(float x, float y, float z)
    : m_x(x), m_y(y), m_z(z)
  {}
  float m_x;
  float m_y;
  float m_z;

  // Sort first by x, than by y and finally by z coordinates.
  bool operator<(const Atom &other) const
  {
    if (m_x < other.m_x)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else if (m_x == other.m_x)
    {
      if (m_y < other.m_y)
      {
        return true;
      }
      else if (m_y == other.m_y)
      {
        if (m_z < other.m_z)
        {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  // To compare two atoms.
  bool operator==(const Atom &other) const
  {
    return m_x == other.m_x && m_y == other.m_y && m_z == other.m_z;
  }
};
```

Now let's define `AtomeDyad` class that consists of two `Atoms`:

```
struct AtomDyad
{
  AtomDyad(const Atom &a1, const Atom &a2)
    : m_a1(a1), m_a2(a2)
  {}
  Atom m_a1;
  Atom m_a2;

  bool operator<(const AtomDyad &other) const
  {
    if (m_a1 == other.m_a2 && m_a2 == other.m_a1)
    {
      return false;
    }

    if (m_a1 < other.m_a1)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else if (m_a1 == other.m_a1)
    {
      if (m_a2 < other.m_a2)
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }  
};
```

Finally, let's store unique `AtomDyads`. A unit test:

```
std::set<AtomDyad> uniqueAtomDyad;

Atom a1(0, 0, 0);
Atom a2(0, 0, 1);
Atom a3(0, 1, 1);
Atom a4(1, 1, 1);

AtomDyad ad1(a1, a2);
AtomDyad ad2(a3, a4);
AtomDyad ad3(a1, a2); // same as ad1
AtomDyad ad4(a4, a3); // swapped ad3
AtomDyad ad5(a1, a1);
AtomDyad ad6(a1, a1);

uniqueAtomDyad.insert(ad1);
uniqueAtomDyad.insert(ad2);
uniqueAtomDyad.insert(ad3); // not unique
uniqueAtomDyad.insert(ad4); // not unique
uniqueAtomDyad.insert(ad5);
uniqueAtomDyad.insert(ad6); // not unique

assert(uniqueAtomDyad.size() == 3);
```

You can check whether an item is added to the set by checking the return value of `std::set::insert()` function.

Comment: using your example I was able to bootstrap my code to achieve what I needed, thank you.